# Doctrine ORM - Prefixing Tables

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-1.2

I'm using Doctrine 1.2, and would like to know how I can achieve mysql table prefixes with it.

So for instance I would like for our system to be deployed twice on the same database, the first the tables can be prefixed with "one_" and the second can be prefixed with "two_".

Anyone got any idea how to accomplish this? I would imagine it is a config setting but I just can't seem to find it.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Generate the tables in the database using doctrine?  Generate two sets of models?

Comment: So like for wordpress, it has the database table prefix 'wp_' by default. Having that in doctrine would allow me to use the same code/system with two separate installations in the se database when traditionally you would need a database for each install instead you have a prefix for each install.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried it but.. from the docs:

```
$manager = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance();
$manager->setAttribute(Doctrine_Core::ATTR_TBLNAME_FORMAT, 'one_%s');
```

Alternatively, you can manually define a table name in your YAML schema:

```
Foo:
  tableName: one_foo
  columns:
    # etc.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm just wondering though.. is this really practical, because presumably you'll be rebuilding models which will entail dropping/creating/rebuilding your database, probably a lot. Which means you'll be dropping both sets of tables each time. Seems a lot more laborious than creating two databases, and defining a connection for each in the Doctrine_Manager.

Comment: It's use case is for shared hosts which only allow one database. Another use case is for demo installs for CMS which due to server permission restrictions won't allow for automatic database creation.

Comment: hi. sorry about the delay. fair enough. so I guess what you could do is define two connections (with the same db credentials etc.) and then use the Doctrine_Manager to grab each instance by name... then set the desired tablename format for each, as above? Don't have time to check if that'll fly right now but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a UML model of the domain, you can use this [UML to Doctrine online service](http://modeling-languages.com/blog/content/launching-uml-php-online-generation-service) to generate different versions of the corresponding Doctrine script, each one with different prefixes for the tables (choosing a prefix is one of the configuration options you can change as part of the generation process)